# How to place a picture in sharedlatex as landscape instead of portrait

Tags: graphics

I have the following image set in sharedlatex:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=17cm]{sensors}
\centering
\caption{Sensor framework}
\end{figure}
```

What is the best way to set this image as landscape? It is set as default in sharedlatex as portrait, but since the image is too big for it is not readable.

Comment: you mean `\includegraphics[angle=270,height=17cm]{sensors}`?

Comment: Well, you can use the option to scale or adjust the image inside with the `\includegraphics` command and the `graphicx` package. If you need to fit the picture you can use `\includegrahics[width=\textwidth]{sensors}` or use the option that @tohecz recommends you.